# DRL compilation error on a generic type property

Tags: java, drools

I'm using drools 6.5.0 / java 1.8.0_131

I got a DRL compilation error on accessing through a generic type property.
Minimized object definition is below.

```
public interface OrderLine<T extends Product> {
    T getProduct();
}

public interface Product {
    String getId();
    String getCategory();
}

// and I have concrete classes, ex. Book, BookOrderLine<Book>, DVD, DVDOrderLine<DVD>, ... etc
```

DRL(snippet) is here

```
when
    $orderLine: OrderLine()

    // compilation failed
    Product(
        id == $orderLine.product.id || category == $orderLine.product.category
    ) from discountProducts
```

this causes below exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/checkorder-not-compiled.drl, line=15, column=0   text=Unable to Analyse Expression id == $orderLine.product.id || category == $orderLine.product.category:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Object.category()]
[Near : {... Line.product.id || category == $orderLine.product.category ....}]
                                                               ^
[Line: 15, Column: 2]]]
```

This is weird because it won't occur when the restriction has single condition like below. Drools could analyze this expression.

```
when
    $orderLine: OrderLine()

    // this is compiled, even if `Product(id == $orderLine.product.id)`
    Product(
        category == $orderLine.product.category
    ) from discountProducts
```

Q. Is this a bug of drools or mvel library ?

Comment: Probably. Why don't you raise a JIRA on the Drools error reporting system?

Comment: @laune, thank you for the comment. I reported this on the JIRA.  https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1724